# Extending a received path

Tags: bash, shell, loops, path

As part of a script to count items in any received directory, I need to recursively check for any sub-directory as well.
For this I need to extend the given argument and add the path of the sub directory to it, for example: for /path/dir1 with sub-directories sub1 and sub2, I need to edit the argument to /path/dir1/sub1 and /path/dir1/sub2 and run the script on them as well.
I tried different things but can't manage to do it properly.

Inside the for loop is where I try to add the sub-directories to the given path, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

- script1.sh gets me the number of items in a folder.
- script2.sh prints the names of sub-directories with a space between.

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$1
count=0
a="$(source script1.sh)"
((count=count+a+1))
b="$(source script2.sh)"
c="$(wc -w <<<  "$b")"
i=0
for i in {1.."$c"}
do
    d="$(cut -f"$i" -d" " <<< "$b")"
    echo "$d"
    (( i += 1 ))
done
echo "$count"
```

Comment: `find -exec ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code has a few problems:

- if any subdirectory contains whitespace in its name, then your script2.sh will produce ambiguous output
- you never add `i` to `count`
- your `wc` and `for` and `cut` is a convoluted way to access the list of directory names
- the indentation is confusing

Here is a simple recursive function that uses bash builtins to avoid calling out to external programs:

```
#!/bin/bash

countdir()(
    declare -i n=0
    if cd "$1" 1>&2; then
        shopt -s dotglob nullglob
        for f in *; do
            if [ -d "$f" ]; then
                n+=$(countdir "$f") # recurse!
            fi
            n+=1
        done
    else
        printf 1>&2 "Access error, ignoring directory: %s\n" "$1"
    fi
    echo $n
)

countdir "$1"
```

- we use `f()()` instead of more usual `f(){}` so `shopt` and `cd` are temporary
- `declare -i` localises `$n` and allows performing arithmetic directly
- following your code, this includes subdirectories in the count as well as their contents
- count total may be wrong if there are any symlinks to directories or files with multiple hardlinks
- invoking with no argument is equivalent to invoking with "." (because `cd ""` is a no-op)